# Identify values for these resonators

Tags: crystal, resonance, clock-speed, quartz

[image]

[image]

I need some help to identify the values of these resonators. Anyone here have experience with such components?

Comment: What do you mean with the values? The frequency? The part number and manufacturer?

Comment: The frequencies

Answer (score 0):

These look similar to the metal case muRata Ceralock series parts. Review markings in the [Ceralock datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/281/p16e-522700.pdf).

This seems to be an even better reference: A [Digikey/TechForm page](https://forum.digikey.com/t/murata-ceralock-resonator-marking/8247) with detailed marking examples for frequency and EIAJ date coding for these muRata resonators.

Answer (score 0):

The othe one reads 600 and the other one 100.

Likely 6 and 10 MHz. You can probe with an oscilloscope.